# MoQ where query on HttpSessionStateBase

Tags: c#, moq

I am trying to mock `HttpRequestBase` and `HttpSessionStateBase` objects and test my code with Moq mocking framework.

This is the relevant part of my setup.

```
_httpSessionStateBase = _mockRepository.Create<HttpSessionStateBase>();
            _motorWebSession = new MotorWebSession
            {
                PersonaIdentifier = Guid.NewGuid(),
                NameIdentifier = Guid.NewGuid(),
                MiCurrentPageId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                MiSessionId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            };

            _httpSessionStateBase.SetupGet(e => e.Count).Returns(1);
            var keysCollection = new NameValueCollection { { "MotorSession", "MotorSession" } };
            _httpSessionStateBase.SetupGet(e => e.Keys).Returns(keysCollection.Keys);
            _httpSessionStateBase.Object[0] = _motorWebSession;
            _httpSessionStateBase.Object["MotorSession"] = _motorWebSession;

_httpContextBase = _mockRepository.Create<HttpContextBase>();
_httpContextBase.SetupGet(h => h.Session).Returns(_httpSessionStateBase.Object);
```

In the current implementation this code is called within a test.

```
var webSession = _httpContext.Current.Session;

var sessionObject = webSession.Keys.Cast<string>()
                    .Where(w => webSession[w] is WebSessionBase)
                    .Select(s => webSession[s])
                    .ToList().FirstOrDefault();
```

During the Where clause `sessionObject` results into `null` which prevents any other subsequent code to run correctly. Is there something wrong I am doing with the setup? Or could the code be altered to work for this setup? It worked with Rhino.Mocks but I am trying to change it to Moq.

Comment: what is `_httpContext.Current`?

Comment: Strict mock that returns `_httpContextBase.Object`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `_httpSessionStateBase.Object["MotorSession"] = _motorWebSession;` call `_httpSessionStateBase.Setup( s => s["MotorSession"]).Returns(_motorWebSession);`. Moq mocked objects can't be assigned directly even through index using the `[]` operator. The correct way to do that is to make a setup.